# js Date too much clever behavior

Tags: javascript

I encounter problem when parsing date via native JS Date object.

```
new Date("I'm really clever date 8745")
```

This expression returns valid Date which was pretty shocking for me. How to prevent this special behavior ?

EDIT: Date interprets last number as year ...

EDIT: Chrome, version (48.0.2564.116)

EDIT: Expected format is "2016-03-20T18:05:53.485Z" (JSON stringify)

Comment: validate all user input

Comment: fwiw, browsers are allowed to try to recover date info from ambiguous input, not sure it's easily predictable or controllable.

Comment: Date is from JSON.stringify, so no user validation

Answer (score 2):

if you intend to "match" any valid date (eg. christmas...), it is far from simple. if istead you want to allow only some format type, i'll go with regexp. here a simple not very extended example:

```
function isprobablyavaliddate(str){
    var allowed = /\d{4}[\\\/-]{1}\d{2}[\\\/-]{1}\d{2}/
    //example allowed date formats: yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy/mm/dd
    return allowed.test(str)
}
var testString = "I'm really clever date 8745"
//catch valid string before doing anything with a date...
if ( isprobablyavaliddate(testString) ) mydate = new Date(testString)
else ...
```

for your valid format requested in your edit: `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z/` (the `^` is for match initial character)

Answer (score 0):

I used regex for testing if string is valid ISO date.

```
        /(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d+([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z))|(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z))|(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z))/;
```

Works perfectly.